# docker mount not updating the files

Tags: docker

I have a sample.txt file which is mounted into my docker container as follows

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd)/sample.txt,target=/sample.txt \
  python:3.8-slim-buster /bin/bash
```

Now I am expecting the sample.txt file to change inside the container whenever i edit it from the host.

But it does not change.

Can anyone help. I wanted the changes to be reflected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a not so know issue with editors changing the inode of the file mounted on the container.
You can check if this is the case by requesting the inode of the file on both ends with `ls -i sample.txt` initially both files should be having the same inode but after making some change to the file with certain editors, the file being edited will be pointing to a different inode.
Try to mount a folder instead of a file as it is the safest way to avoid this situation.

Comment: I got this. But I have to place a .env file in my reactjs project. I don't think I can place .env file inside folder. Because the project will not recognize.

Comment: Use the `set backupcopy yes` option in the `.vimrc` file or use nano, in both ways the inode remains the same. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36467/why-inode-value-changes-when-we-edit-in-vi-editor